# Read files from URL

Tags: vbscript

Is it possible to read files like .css and .js from a URL? For instance, I have a file, which is located at `http://main/shared/css/main.css`, and want to read this file and store its content in another file at `c:\main.txt`. I know how to read files in local drives but not sure how to do it for a URL. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is possible (as soon as the PC you run the VBScript on has an internet access of course!), and I think you'll find you answer in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204759/http-get-in-vbs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download a file with VBS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973136/download-a-file-with-vbs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874) for this:

```
url = "http://main/shared/css/main.css"

Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
req.open "GET", url, False
req.send

If req.Status = 200 Then
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  fso.OpenTextFile("C:\main.txt", 2).Write req.responseText
End If
```

Comment: Thank u for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

Yes as long as you know the file names in question you should be able to do a simple XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score -2):

```html
url = "http://main/shared/css/main.css"

Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
req.open "GET", url, False
req.send

If req.Status = 200 Then
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  fso.OpenTextFile("C:\main.txt", 8, true, 0).Write req.responseText
End If
```

> A slight amend to the OpenTextFile line so the text file is created
>   locally if it does not exist.