# Retrieve information from JSON string thru VBScript

Tags: json, vbscript, chilkat

I'm trying to get some information from that [JSON-string](https://api.crypto-bridge.org/api/v1/ticker).

I found an [example](https://www.example-code.com/vbscript/json_array_load_and_parse.asp) how to do and and tried to adapt if for my task:

```
Dim fso, outFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set outFile = fso.CreateTextFile("output.txt", True)

'  A JSON array must be loaded using JsonArray:
set jsonArray = CreateObject("Chilkat_9_5_0.JsonArray")

success = jsonArray.Load("https://api.crypto-bridge.org/api/v1/ticker")

If (success <> 1) Then
    outFile.WriteLine(jsonArray.LastErrorText)  '!!! "Unable to get array at index 0."
    WScript.Quit
End If

'  Examine the values:
i = 0
Do While i < jsonArray.Size
    ' jsonObj is a Chilkat_9_5_0.JsonObject
    Set jsonObj = jsonArray.ObjectAt(i)
    outFile.WriteLine(i & ": " & jsonObj.StringOf("last"))

    i = i + 1
Loop

outFile.Close
```

And all I get in output.txt is

```
 ChilkatLog:
  Load:
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.71
    Unable to get array at index 0.
  --Load
--ChilkatLog
```

Could you help me please to understand what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt [read the documentation](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatJsonArrayRef.html)

> #### Load`(jsonArray As String) As Long`
>
> **Introduced in version 9.5.0.64**
>
> Loads a JSON array from a string. A JSON array must begin with a "[" and end with a "]".
>
> Note: The Load method causes the JsonArray to detach and become it's own JSON document. It should only be called on new instances of the JsonArray. See the example below.
>
> Returns 1 for success, 0 for failure.

The `Load()` method expects a JSON Array string not a URL to a JSON Array. First use XHR to download the JSON into a string then call `jsonArray.Load(download_json_string)`.

Simple example of an XHR would be;

```
Dim url, req, json
url = "https://api.crypto-bridge.org/api/v1/ticker"

Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
Call req.Open("GET", url, False)
Call req.Send()

If req.Status = 200 Then
  json = req.responseText
End If
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Read files from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17193257/692942)