# (Cross-Script) Download latest PowerShell Core

Tags: bash, powershell, cross-platform, x86-64

Windows: Assuming that `PowerShell Core is not installed on Windows` scenario.

Linux : Assuming that `PowerShell Core was not installed by default and need to make a shell script to install it` scenario.

MacOS : Assuming that `Tried other method to download latest PS Core than Microsoft provided script, but failed. Removing the files, but found leftovers that must be removed by the script`

---

How to download and install latest `PowerShell Core` of a specified channel (release , beta, rc)
for specified OS `(-win- ; -osx ; -1.ubuntu-18.04-)` with specified architecture `(-amd64 ; -x86 ; -x64)` using bash or powershell? (Without requiring manual config)

Here's the code :

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$location = Get-Location
$architecture = "x" + (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).AddressWidth
$assetName = "PowerShell-*-win-$architecture.msi"

$gitHubApi = 'https://api.github.com/repos/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/latest'
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $gitHubApi -UseBasicParsing
$json = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$release = $json.assets | Where-Object Name -like $assetName


Invoke-WebRequest $release.browser_download_url -OutFile "$location\$($release.name)"

Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/A $($release.name) /I $location\$($release.name) /quiet /qb ADD_EXPLORER_CONTEXT_MENU_OPENPOWERSHELL=1 REGISTER_MANIFEST=1 ENABLE_PSREMOTING=1'

Write-Host Ok
```

Comment: Please edit your original question to include details on what code you have tried, what error messages you got or how the result was different from what you expected.

Comment: There is `https://aka.ms/install-powershell.ps1`, which, of course, requires that _some_ version of PowerShell is already installed, so it works on _Windows_, where you can run from Windows PowerShell, but not on Unix-like platforms. On Unix-like platforms, the simplest way to install is via the various package managers or direct downloads - see [instructions for Linux distros](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux) and for [macOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-macos).

Comment: I assume that the code you're showing already works _on Windows_, and now you're looking for something analogous on _Unix-like_ platforms? If so, please make that clearer in your question.

Comment: Question: When i tested ```install-powershell.ps1``` ,  it actually download and installs latest ```PowerShell Core``` for Windows, i noticed it doesn't appear as a program i.e. shows at star menu. Why? And, do y'know a way to download powershell core without powershell?

Comment: Your handle is WinScriptDev, which makes one assume you've been at this scripting thing for a while. So, for this download without PowerShell question. Why are you not looking to use VBScript or WMI for that? Both are capable tools for such use cases. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973136/download-a-file-with-vbs. Thus using terminals on non-Win. Example: https://osxdaily.com/2007/05/11/download-files-from-the-web-via-the-os-x-command-line/

Comment: There is also `https://aka.ms/install-powershell.sh`