# how to save a downloaded excel file using vba

Tags: html, vba, download

I made a simple VBA code that go to a link and download a Excel file, the link is an intermediate HTML page which then downloads the file, i just need to access, but now i need to save it. I am a noob at VBA, can anyone help me? Follow the code Bellow

```
Private pWebAddress As String

Public Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute _
Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Public Sub NewShell(cmdLine As String, lngWindowHndl As Long)
    ShellExecute lngWindowHndl, "open", cmdLine, "", "", 1
End Sub

Public Sub WebPage()
    Let pWebAddress = "https://imea.com.br/imea-site/arquivo-externo?categoria=relatorio-de-mercado&arquivo=cup-milho&numeropublicacao=4"
    
    Call NewShell(pWebAddress, 3)
```

i Have already researched a lot, but none of the ones i have seen had be of help.

---

**UPDATE**
With the help of Tim, i sucessfully made the vba code, it was simple.

```
        Dim wb As Workbook
        
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("PastTheLinkHere")
        wb.SaveAs "PastTheDestinationHere"
        wb.Close
        
        End Sub
```

What i really needed was to make the link a direct link, and with help of Tim it was easy. Thank you Tim.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973136/download-a-file-with-vbs) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877389/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-vba-without-internet-explorer). Pro tip - this isn't "excel-file specific". What you're looking for is simply - http(s) file download vba.

Comment: From within excel, have you tried `Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open("https://imea.com.br/imea-site/arquivo-externo?categoria=relatorio-de-mercado&arquivo=cup-milho&numeropublicacao=4"): wb.SaveAs [pathHere]` ?

Comment: Hi, it does not save the same file that is downloaded from the page

Comment: Your URL doesn't lead directly to an Excel file, but to an intermediate HTML page which then downloads the file.

Comment: Yes, that's it, you can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This URL:
`https://imea.com.br/imea-site/arquivo-externo?categoria=relatorio-de-mercado&arquivo=cup-milho&numeropublicacao=4`

leads to a page with this javascript which builds the final URL:

```js
methods: {
        laodMetadata() {
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            this.categoria = urlParams.get("categoria");
            this.safra = urlParams.get("safra");
            this.arquivo = urlParams.get("arquivo");
            this.numeropublicacao = urlParams.get("numeropublicacao");
        },
        async loadData() {
            this.loading = true;
            const url = "https://publicacoes.imea.com.br";
            this.url = url;
            if (this.categoria != null)
                this.url = this.url + `/${this.categoria}`;
            if (this.safra != null) this.url = this.url + `/${this.safra}`;
            if (this.arquivo != null) this.url = this.url + `/${this.arquivo}`;
            if (this.numeropublicacao != null)
                this.url = this.url + `/${this.numeropublicacao}`;
            return this.url;
        },
```

The final URL is then:

`https://publicacoes.imea.com.br/relatorio-de-mercado/cup-milho/4`

So this works and opens the Excel file directly in Excel:

```vb
Workbooks.Open "https://publicacoes.imea.com.br/relatorio-de-mercado/cup-milho/4"
```

You could translate that js into VBA to make a function which would translate the first URL into the second one.

```vb
Function tester()
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://imea.com.br/imea-site/arquivo-externo?" & _
          "categoria=relatorio-de-mercado&arquivo=cup-milho&numeropublicacao=4"
          
    Debug.Print MapToDownloadUrl(url)
End Function

Function MapToDownloadUrl(url As String) As String
    Dim urlNew As String, dict As Object, e
    
    Set dict = ParseQuerystring(url)
    If dict Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    urlNew = "https://publicacoes.imea.com.br"
    For Each e In Array("categoria", "arquivo", "numeropublicacao")
        If dict.exists(e) Then urlNew = urlNew & "/" & dict(e)
    Next e
    MapToDownloadUrl = urlNew
End Function

'Parse out the querystring parameters from a URL as a dictionary
Function ParseQuerystring(url) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, arr, arrQs, e
    arr = Split(url, "?")
    If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
        Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        dict.comparemode = 1 'case-insensitive
        arrQs = Split(arr(1), "&")
        For Each e In arrQs
            If InStr(e, "=") > 0 Then
                arr = Split(e, "=")
                If UBound(arr) = 1 Then dict.Add arr(0), arr(1)
            End If
        Next e
        Set ParseQuerystring = dict
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: WOW, I am really grateful that you took some of your time to help me. Thank You.
This function is Perfect for what i need.

Comment: but as i said, i am beginner, so i don't know how i use this script, i know what it does, but when i active him, i Don't Know where the link goes.

Comment: I took the first link as a exemple and edited the others, Thank you for the help.

Comment: The modified link prints to the Immediate pane in the VB editor  - you can show it by pressing Ctrl+G